# Как подключиться к базе данных sqlite через интернет

Tags: java, sqlite

Как подключиться к базе данных sqlite через интернет?

Может можно как-то через `Class.forName()` ?

Comment: Вот эта ссылка может вам помочь: https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-java/sqlite-jdbc-driver/. Если кратко - вам надо подключить драйвер для БД в виде библиотеки, после чего этот драйвер использовать для подключения к БД.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sqlite не предназначена для работы через интернет. Это бд именно для локального хранения. Это не клиент-серверна БД, которая предназначена для конкурентного доступа.

Но если очень нужно, можно использовать доп. средства (нужно только найти подходящие для используемого окружения), чтобы примонтировать удалённое хранилище как локальный диск. И работать с бд с обычного (хоть и виртуального) диска.

Существуют ещё проекты вроде SQLitening, но не знаю, насколько в данном случае такое решение может быть уместно.

Comment: по поводу "примонтировать удалённое" я бы переузнал, насколько безошибочно и быстро оно заработает.

Comment: @SergeiKirjanov я специально отметил, что "если очень нужно". Т.к. в любом случае это явно не целевое использование. Но я, например, лично имел положительный опыт с использованием DriveMaker, который использовался для примонтирования FTP в качестве диска и доступа к БД сайта. Для периодического просмотра данных или небольших корректировок, а также для локальной отладки и отлавливания багов, которые лезут бывает только на боевой БД, это было более чем приемлемое решение.